# C Remove leading and trailing spaces in string by pointer manipulation only

Tags: c, string, pointers, trim, c-strings

I've been trying to remove leading and trailing spaces from a C string by only manipulating pointers (not copying characters to the char array). The idea so far has been something like this:

```
void trim_string(char *str)
{
    char *ptr = str;

    // This part removes leading spaces
    while(*ptr == ' ') ++ptr;
    while (*str++ = *ptr++);

    // This part removes trailing spaces
    str--;
    while(*str == ' ') --str;
    str++;
    *str = *ptr;
}
```

However the part that removes the trailing spaces does not work.

After the remove leading spaces part, *str and *ptr should be sitting at the end of the string; the '\0' character. The idea was to move one of the pointers backward through the string until a non-space character was detected, while the other pointer still pointed to the '\0'. Then point the last space character to the other pointer (which still points at '\0'), to terminate the string.

What would be the correct way to move / reassign the null pointer for the trailing spaces part with that logic?

Comment: If you want to trim anything, then you need to do `*str = 0` or `str[i] = 0` for some value of `i`. But you only seems to be doing `*str = *ptr`. If the value of `*ptr` happens to be 0, then you'll be trimming the end of the string pointed by `str`. But is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do:

```
while (*str++ = *ptr++);
```

Accessing the contents pointed by `ptr` is no longer a valid operation past this point (it can lead to a memory access violation, and more generally - undefined behavior of your program).

But this is exactly what you do at the last line of your code:

```
*str = *ptr;
```

Apart from that, note that in order to trim the string pointed by `str`, you need to do either one of the following:

- `*str = 0`
- `str[i] = 0` for some non-negative integer value of `i`

So there is really no point in doing `*str = *ptr` when your purpose is trimming that string.